# How to combine every 5 lists inside of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, append, iteration

I have a large list of lists, for example:

```
list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['1234'], ['d'], ['e'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['56']]
```

I would like to combine every 5 lists into one list of elements and so on. 
I am having total of 150995 lists inside a list.

Expected output:

```
new_list = [['a' , 'b', 'c', '1234', 'd'], ['e', 'g', 'h', 'i', '56']]
```

I tried with below code. but it is flattens to one list.

```
list(zip(*list)[0])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: would flatten + group as evenly sized chunks would do? your lists contain just 1 element? or can contain something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you basically want to group evenly sized chunks of lists. It's possible using `itertools.chain` and slicing with `range` and a step of 5

```
import itertools

lst = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['1234'], ['d'], ['e'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['56']]

result = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.islice(lst,i,i+5))) for i in range(0,len(lst),5)]


print(result)
```

result:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', '1234', 'd'], ['e', 'g', 'h', 'i', '56']]
```

notes:

- using `itertools.islice` avoids a standard `lst[i:i+5]` slicing that creates a useless `list` object
- it works even when the number of elements isn't divisible by 5.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> li = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['1234'], ['d'], ['e'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['56']]
```

You can do:

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(*[iter([e for sublist in li for e in sublist])]*5)))
[['a', 'b', 'c', '1234', 'd'], ['e', 'g', 'h', 'i', '56']]
```

Or,

```
>>> [[e for sublist in lst[i:i+5] for e in sublist] for i in range(0,len(lst),5)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', '1234', 'd'], ['e', 'g', 'h', 'i', '56']]
```

Comment: how does map function takes "list" keyword as first argument?

Comment: Map calls the first function on all the elements of the second function and returns a generator. `list` isn't a keyword, it's a function.

Comment: @karthikeayan `list` is not a keyword. It is merely the name of a built-in function. It is a normal variable in that respect, you can assign whatever you want to it: `list = "you shouldn't do this"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.chain` to flatten the list and `itertools.zip_longest` to group the elemensts in chunks of 5

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest, chain
>>> n = 5
>>> list(zip_longest(*[chain(*List)]*n))    
[('a', 'b', 'c', '1234', 'd'), ('e', 'g', 'h', 'i', '56')]
```

If you are not happy with the result being list of tuples, you can convert the individual elements from tuple to list using `map`

```
>>> list(map(list, zip_longest(*[chain(*List)]*5)))
[['a', 'b', 'c', '1234', 'd'], ['e', 'g', 'h', 'i', '56']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is convenient since it uses nothing besides `numpy`

If your list always has elements divisible by 5, then

```
import numpy as np
oldlist = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['1234'], ['d'], ['e'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['56']]
newlist = np.reshape(oldlist,(len(oldlist)//5,5)).T.tolist()
```

newlist will have your desired output of

```
[['a' , 'b', 'c', '1234', 'd'], ['e', 'g', 'h', 'i', '56']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Many good solutions already. I just wanted to add one more possiblity that is using a custom `Iterator` like so:

```
from itertools import chain


class MyIter:
    def __init__(self, lists,n_first):
        self.lists = lists
        self.index = 0
        self.n_first = n_first

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index < len(self.lists):

            temp = list(chain(*self.lists[self.index:min(self.index+self.n_first,len(self.lists))]))
            self.index += self.n_first
            return temp
        else:
            raise StopIteration

_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['1234'], ['d'], ['e'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['56']]

print(list(MyIter(_list,5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `len(list)` is a multiple of 5, the following solution works:

```
list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['1234'], ['d'], ['e'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['56']]
row = int(len(list)/5)
new_list = [i.tolist() for i in np.array(list).reshape((row,5))]
print (new_list)
```

resulting in

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', '1234', 'd'], ['e', 'g', 'h', 'i', '56']]
```

Comment: Apparently. I was working on it while you already posted. But just another road to reach the same destination ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-library list comprehension solution:

```
>>> L = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['1234'], ['d'], ['e'], ['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['56']]
>>> [[j[0] for j in L[i:i+5]] for i in range(0, len(L), 5)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', '1234', 'd'], ['e', 'g', 'h', 'i', '56']]
```

By the way, calling your list `list` redefines a builtin function.